# Why don't I get positive values when trying to divide two integers (without using multiplication, div, mod, log)?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

In the `int divide()` method, `Math.abs()` is returning negative values for upper and lower boundary values. Even if I multiply it with *-1 the negative is not converting into positive value (`div` is showing a negative value), but the same methods works when I tried `Math.abs()` in `main()` method.

```java
public class Mass {
    public static int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
           int ans =0;
        long val  = Math.abs(divisor);
        long  div = Math.abs(dividend);
            System.out.println(div);
        for(int i =1;i<=div;i++){
            val--;
            if(val ==0){
                ans++;
                val = Math.abs(divisor);
            }
        }
        if((dividend<0 && divisor >0 ) || (dividend >0 && divisor<0) ){
            ans = ans *(-1);
        }

        return ans;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int a= divide(-2147483648, -2);
    
       System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Why do I have trouble with negative values?

Comment: maybe it would have been better to use `Math.absExact()` instead of `Math.abs()` (the first method is provided exactly for this case)

Comment: @user16320675 -- Now It's showing error instead of answer 0    i,e `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Overflow to represent absolute value of Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: that is exactly the reason for using that method - so you know that `2147483648` is not a valid value for `int`, or that `-2147483648` cannot be converted to a positive `int`

Comment: `ans = -ans` and not `ans = ans * -1` or you used multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

`int`s in Java have 32 bits, so the min is -2147483648 and the max is 2147483647. This means you get overflow when you do abs(min).

I think actually the easiest way to fix this is just working with negative numbers, something like this:

```
public int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
    if (divisor == 0 || dividend == Integer.MIN_VALUE && divisor == -1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (dividend == 0) return 0;
    if (divisor == 1) return dividend; // required for dividend = MIN_VALUE
    boolean negative = false;
    if (dividend > 0) dividend = -dividend; else negative = true;
    if (divisor > 0) divisor = -divisor; else negative = !negative;
    int result = 0;
    for (; dividend <= divisor; result++) dividend -= divisor;
    return negative ? -result : result;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the terminating condition of the `for` loop use `>=`?

Comment: @RaffleBuffle no because we are working with negative numbers to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
//works for integers only

public class MathSkills {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(dividend(100,4));

    }
    public static int dividend(int a, int b) {
        int ans=0;
        for(;a>=b;ans++) {
            a=a-b;
        }
    
        return ans;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it only works for positive numbers. If a >= b will be false at first iteration already for negative numbers.

Comment: Basically division is nothing but substract a dividend repeatedly by divisor until the dividend becomes less than divisor. The number times it got subtracted is the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).